# mikrotik joining two subnets

Tags: networking, mikrotik

I have two subnets which are geographically separated, connected by a wireless point to point link (5Mbps). Both networks are connected to internet through their own separate ILL WAN links which are configured on MikroTik routers. I want to connect the subnets through the routers. 
The scenario is :

Site 1:

192.168.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 192.168.10.1/24    ---- connected to local LAN

10.10.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 10.10.10.1/24      ---- connected to local LAN

I want to connect the two LANs together so that there is a seamless traffic between the two.

NO FIREWALL rules on either routers.
Only source NAT masquerade on WAN links on both routers.
NO destination NAT

I have tried the below, which, obviously does not work.

Site 1:

192.168.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 192.168.10.1/24    ---- connected to local LAN
Ether3 10.10.10.10/24     ---- P2P between Site 1 and 2

10.10.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 10.10.10.1/24      ---- connected to local LAN
Ether3 192.168.10.10/24   ---- P2P between Site 1 and 2

What am I missing? (Beside, looks like everything?)

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

As far as i got:

Head Office:

Public IP: 11.22.33.44

Private IP: 192.168.10.0/24

---

Branch:

Public IP: 12.23.34.45
Private IP: 192.168.1.0/24

Have a look at This:
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/L2TP